# Overriding pressBegan and menu button on tvOS

Tags: swift, uikit, tvos

I have one view controller with many subviews. When one presses `Menu` button, my app should perform some actions. But if there wasn't any "active" actions, my app should close.

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    guard let type = presses.first?.type else { return }

    //...

    if falls == true && type == .Menu {
        super.pressesBegan(presses, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

At first time, this code works as should. But if I reopen app and press `Menu` button, app closes, however `super` function wasn't called.

How should I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a dirty hack:

1. Removed `super` call:

   ```
   super.pressesBegan(presses, withEvent: event)
   ```
2. Call `suspend` on `UIApplication` when I need to close the app

   ```
   if type == .Menu && falls == true {
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().performSelector(Selector("suspend"))
   }
   ```